# How do you loop through an input array and build an output array by pushing items on it using Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, include, duplicates

I'm taking a class and one of the problems requires us to build a ruby script. In the script define a method call `unique`, which will accept an argument of an array. Then have the method remove duplicate items from an array. (Example: `unique([1,2,3,2,1,6,9])` would return `[1,2,3,6,9]`). We have to implement a version that uses the `array.uniq` method and implement one that doesn't; this version will loop through the input array and build an output array by pushing items on it, depending on whether or not it is `included?` in the array.

This is what I have written so far.  There are 3 methods.  The first uses the `array.uniq` and functions as expected. The second is an attempt to use `.include?`, but it returns all of the numbers in the array, obviously. Not sure what I was doing there... The third was a shot in the dark at a way to see if the number is being duplicated and if it is, not add it to the `test_array`.

Can anyone help this new guy figure out what I'm doing wrong and what I should be doing? Thank you all in advance!

```
numbers = [1,2,3,2,1,6,9]

def unique(array)
  u_num = array.uniq
  puts "These are the numbers in the array #{array} without duplicates: #{u_num}"
end

puts unique(numbers)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

new_array = []

numbers.each do |number|
  if numbers.include?(number)
    new_array << number
  end
end

puts "#{new_array}"

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------  

test_array = []

numbers.each do |number|
  if number.detect { |i| numbers }
    test_array << i
  end
end

puts "#{test_array}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check your logic. To build an array of unique elements, you want to add each element to the new array *unless the new array already includes the element*. Ruby let's you write this logic pretty much verbatim:

```
new_array << number unless new_array.include? number
```

Comment: Thank you! The more I learn Ruby the cooler I think this language is, it really does have a human-readable solution for nearly everything! Thanks so much for the help @Max!